# WIX - How to selectively uninstall the <Bundle>

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to retain the previous versions of my Bootstrapper App, how to achieve this?

I know that we can use the Upgrade tag in MSI where we can identify the different versions and perform uninstall operations base on those.

Now, I have a Bundle Application that has one or more MSI which use some UpgradeCode. Each time I create a new build I just version up the MSI and this Bundle Application. When I proceed with installing of later version of Bundle App, it uninstall the previous Bundle version, which is not what I want. I want to retain the previous versions of my Bundle Application.

Is there anything like UpgradeVersion in Bundle as well, where we would be able to identify the diferent versions and do selectively uninstall.

My Bundle file code snippet :

```
    <Bundle Name="myApp"
          Version="1.0.0.0"
          Manufacturer="Myself"
          UpgradeCode="SOME-GUID">

          <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
          ...
          </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id= 'WindowsInstaller45'/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id ='NetFx45Offline'/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id ='MY_MSI'/>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>

<Fragment  Id ='PkgFragments'>
<PackageGroup Id ="MY_MSI">
      <MsiPackage SourceFile= "$(var.Installer.TargetPath)"
                  Id="MYAPP"
                  Cache ="yes"
                  Visible ="no"
                  DisplayInternalUI ="no"
                  Permanent="no">
        <MsiProperty Name='INSTALLLOCATION' Value='[InstallFolder]' />
        <MsiProperty Name='SELECT_UNINST' Value='[UninstallPrevVersion]' />
      </MsiPackage>
</PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

My Product WIX file code snippet

```
<Product Id="*"
           Name="$(var.ProductName)"
           Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
           Manufacturer="$(var.ManufacturerName)"
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

    <Property Id="SELECT_UNINST" Secure="yes">1</Property>

    <Upgrade Id="SOME-GUID2">
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0.0" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="yes" Property="UNINSTALL_PREV_VERSION" />
    </Upgrade>

    <CustomAction Id="UninstPrev" Property="UNINSTALL_PREV_VERSION" Value="0" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="UninstPrev" Before="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[SELECT_UNINST <> 1]]></Custom>
      <RemoveExistingProducts Overridable="no" After="UninstPrev"></RemoveExistingProducts>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

</Product>
```

Comment: Wanting your product to remain behind during **upgrade** is completely contrary to what upgrade entails. If you want them to remain behind, don't treat them as the same product, give them new upgrade GUIDs and product GUIDs. Keep a list of each upgrade guid and when you want to delete it add a <RelatedBundle> tag referencing the specific upgrade GUID you want to remove and handle OnPlanRelatedBundle accordingly in your BootstrapperApplication dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put this as an answer too.

If you don't want to remove your previous versions don't treat the new version as an upgrade to the old one. This means change the upgrade GUID and change the product GUID. If you need to remove a specific version, add the bundle as a <RelatedBundle> in your Bundle definition and properly handle OnPlanRelatedBundle in your Bootstrapper Application.

```
<RelatedBundle Action="Detect" Id="$(var.ProductVersion622UpgradeGUID)"/>
```

Additionally, any msi packages you install *also* would need to employ the same behaviour of new upgrade GUIDs if you don't want removal between "upgrades". Keep a list of which GUIDs are with which released versions. If you want to remove specific versions in a release of your msi you need to add

```
<Upgrade Id="$(var.Version6InstallerUpgradeGUID)" >
    <UpgradeVersion
        IncludeMaximum ="no"
        IncludeMinimum="yes"
        Maximum="6.0.0.1"
        Minimum="6.0.0.0"
        MigrateFeatures="no"
        Property="V6FOUND"
        OnlyDetect="no" />      
</Upgrade>
```

I would consider this requirement very odd and would suggest you really think upon whether or not you really want to support this kind of behaviour.

Also to note, the entry in the ARP for the bootstrapper existing doesn't necessarily mean the products it installed are still on the system. You can test this by always setting `pRequestedState = RequestState.Present;` in OnPlanRelatedBundle and setting your msi packages to visible="yes". You will have the old bundle listed in the ARP but the packages it installs were probably upgraded by the newer version so it's just an entry that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you so much for the reply. It is true that this requirement is quite odd. Actually during our installation we are asking user whether he want to uninstall some of the specific previous versions. Now, even if I provide a different GUID to new installer, I won't be able to selectively put the <RelatedBundle> corresponding to those IDs during run time. MSI give me that option through <UpgradeVersion> but I am not able to see something similar in <Bundle>

Comment: My flow is something like..... I have a Custom UI that is build in WPF a Bundle that packages WPF and actual Wix installer. Now, the entry in the ARP should be that of Bundle and not MSI (as I want my Custom UI to be displayed during Uninstallation). Which left me just one option, I would upgrade my Bundle as well. So, at the end lets say if I have version 1.0.0.0 installed then during installing 2.0.0.0 I will ask user if he want to uninstall 1.0.0.0 .If the user select YES then 2.0.0.0 should Identify the previous version(s).

Comment: Without seeing your whole product I can't understand why you want to leave behind a previous version. If they aren't upgrades of a product, don't treat them as upgrades and use related bundles. Handle the DetectRelatedBundle and display the appropriate UI information then based on user's choice handle OnPlanRelatedBundle event to request the bundle be uninstalled or left behind. If the MSIs contained in both bundles are upgrading themselves then even if you leave the old bundle behind none of the actual product it installed exist on the machine anymore so what's the point in having it in ARP?